# Replace string at position

Tags: string, position, stata, substr

I have a string variable in Stata for unique id codes with different structures where I want to i) replace a specific character at a specific position (erroneous data entry) and ii) keep the last part in a new variable that starts after some

To illustrate, some of my id's are in the following structure: 000XXXX000XXXX000001234560780912340567

where the X's are string characters which of some are wrong, for example there are numbers at the 4th X (position 7) which I want to replace with the correct character.

Regarding ii), the last part is a unique number sequence which I want to keep in a new variable, the problem is that the length of this sequence varies and thus does not start at the same position. It seems however that it always starts after `"00"` which is where I assume makes sense to start it.

I have tried `substr()` and `subinstr()` without being able to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clear 
set obs 1 
gen whatever = "000XXXX000XXXX000001234560780912340567"
replace whatever = substr(whatever, 1, 6) + "Y" + substr(whatever, 7, .)

gen wanted = substr(whatever, strrpos(whatever, "00") + 2, .)

di whatever[1]
di wanted[1]
```

Results:

```
. di whatever[1]
000XXXYX000XXXX000001234560780912340567

. di wanted[1]
1234560780912340567
```